# How to save and load input from multiple entry boxes in python 3.8

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

So I'm comepletly new to coding (just started a few days ago) and I am making an account manager where the user can store account Id's and passwords. Now how do I save the entered information (multiple entry fields) and load it when opening the program again .Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Account manager")
window.geometry("250x250")

accesscode = ""




def add():
    ID = tk.Label(root, text="Account/ID:")
    ID.pack()
    global Account
    Account = tk.Entry(root, width=35, show="*")
    Account.pack()
    PW = tk.Label(root, text="Password")
    PW.pack()
    global Password
    Password = tk.Entry(root, width=35, show="*")
    Password.pack()
    linebreak = tk.Label(root, text=" ")
    linebreak.pack()



def show():
    Account.config(show="")
    Password.config(show="")

def granted():
    if Access_code_entry.get() == accesscode:
        window.destroy()
        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("Account Manager")
        root.geometry("450x450")
        Welcome_message = tk.Label(root, text='Welcome')
        Welcome_message.pack(padx=20, pady=0)
        Add = tk.Button(root, text="+", command=add)
        Add.pack()
        Show = tk.Button(root, text="SHOW", width=4, command=show)
        Show.pack()
        save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Save")
        save_button.pack()
        add()
    else:
        window.destroy()


Ask_code = tk.Label(window, text="Enter the main access code:")
Ask_code.pack()

Access_code_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=35, show="*")
Access_code_entry.insert("0", accesscode)
Access_code_entry.pack()

Access = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", width=5, command=granted)
Access.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.dump) and [Tutorial - 7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can save data locally on your machine, or to the cloud.

I will assume you want to save the data locally, so here are the steps you want to take. I find it much easier to find the information I need by breaking a large process into multiple steps.

First I recommend you gather all of your data into one object, whether it be a list `[]` or a dictionary `{}`. For each entry widget in your program, you will need to get the data from that entry, and place it into your object.

Once you have a single object with all of your data that you want to save, you will need to save it to a file. This step requires you to create a new file at a location of your choice, and set the content of the file to your object.

To retrieve the data, you will need to open the file you previously saved, copy the data inside of it, and distribute the contents of the list or dictionary to the appropriate entry widgets in your program.

Finding the answers on how to complete each step should be easier for you to find, try not to get overwhelmed by the number of steps necessary. :)

Personally I find that [Effbot.org](http://effbot.org/) is a great resource for anything related to tkinter.

Good luck!